# Online Exam conduct in my website in php

Tags: php

I want to add a page in  my website by which I want conduct online exams. I want that my page is activate for 3 hours only. After 3 hours the page will submit itself as happens in online exams. Can any one give me any script how to make my page time constraint?

Comment: You need to do this in Javascript. PHP doesn't run until the user submits the form.

Comment: Read on javascript setInterval()

Comment: Javascript is not the whole answer. Disabling javascript in the browser would give somebody unlimited time to do the exam. Server side validation of the time taken would be needed too.

Comment: I prefer you buy available online scripts in market as starting point for it. This will save you time, cost and testing efforts.

Below is one of the fine scripts that I worked it and it worked like charm. Using this as base I developed a online testing portal of over 1000 users using computer adaptive test.

http://codecanyon.net/item/online-skills-assessment/9379895

It is a good starting point for people looking to develop Online Exam System

Answer (score 1):

```
$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

extract the `hour` from the `date` and do this

```
if ($hour > 10800){ // 10800 which is equal to 3 hours in seconds.

    submit the exam

}
```

don't rely on `javascript` to set the time because the `javascript` may be disabled.